# Correct use of cross validation in LibsSVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, python, libsvm

I am classifying data points from two different groups using `LibSVM`.

I do the following:

1. Creating the input file for `LibSVM`. In the input file, I put all the data I have.
2. Scaling it (using `svm-scale`).
3. Using `grid.py` of `libSVM` for choosing `gamma` and `c` parameters.
4. Using `svm-train` for training. I use the entire dataset. I also use the `-v 10` option for 10-fold cross validation (`svm-train flag`).

**My questions are**:

a. Is the `-v 10` option of cross validation can replace the testing step?

b. The result given by the steps above is suspiciously high (96%), and so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong?

c. Could the use of `grid.py` for parameter selection before the train + cross validation damage the results (as if I were testing on data I've already trained)?

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you are mixing a couple of things up. First of all, cross-validation is used to get an accurate idea of the *generalization error* when certain tuning parameters are used.

You can use `svm-train` in k-fold cross-validation mode using the `-v k` flag. In this mode, `svm-train` does not output a model -- just a cross-validated estimate of the generalization performance.

`grid.py` is basically a wrapper around `svm-train` in cross-validation mode. It allows you to easily assess the best parameter tuple out of a given set of options via cross-validation. It is essentially a loop over the specified parameter tuples which performs cross-validation.

> a. Is the -v 10 option of cross validation can replace the testing step?

Not entirely. Cross-validation is indeed used to get an estimate of the generalization performance of a model, but when performing cross-validation the entire training set is never used to construct a single model. The typical steps are (i) find optimal tuning parameters using cross-validation, (ii) train a model using these optimal parameters on the full training set and (iii) test this model on the test set.

> b. The result given by the steps above is suspiciously high (96%), and so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong?

Don't worry, be happy. Such classification accuracies are quite feasible for a wide range of problems.

> c. Could the use of grid.py for parameter selection before the train + cross validation damage the results (as if I were testing on data I've already trained)?

`grid.py` does cross-validation for you. There is no point to perform cross-validation again after you ran `grid.py`.

Comment: But there is a point to do nested cross-validation, i.e. cross-validate the whole [select params with CV on training + test on independent set] procedure. Single test may be sometimes pretty deceiving.

Comment: @mbq yes, that is certainly true. However, based on the question, I assume the OP is a novice, and hence kept things simple to avoid extra confusion.